# fwprintf puts carriage-return before linefeed

Tags: c, winapi, file-io, utf-8, carriage-return

My WinAPI program aims to take text from an [Edit control](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb775456.aspx) and save it to a file.

When [`fopen`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yeby3zcb.aspx) creates the file in text mode `"w"`, then [`fprintf`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xkh07fe2.aspx) makes linefeed `LF` character be preceded by a carriage-return `CR`.

```
HWND hEdit = CreateWindowA( "Edit", NULL, WS_CHILD|ES_MULTILINE, 0, 0, 100, 100, 
                            hWnd, (HMENU)ID_EDITORE, GetModuleHandle(NULL), NULL );
// Input in Edit control a single line break "\r\n"
int num = GetWindowTextLength(hEdit);
char buffer[num+1];
GetWindowText( hEdit, buffer, num+1 );
FILE* file = fopen( "test.txt", "w" );
fprintf( file, "%s", buffer );
```

Above code doesn't write `CR` `LF` in the file, but:

> `CR` `CR` `LF` (0D 0D 0A)

I know here in the ANSI version the solution is to open the file in binary mode: `"wb"` instead of `"w"`, that makes no `CR` `LF` translation or character conversion occur during output.

But I want to input Unicode characters in Edit control, and have the file encoded UTF-8 with BOM.
So what about the wide-character versions [`_wfopen`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yeby3zcb.aspx) and [`fwprintf`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xkh07fe2.aspx)?

```
HWND hEdit = CreateWindowW( L"Edit", ... );
// Input in Edit control a single line break "\r\n"
int num = GetWindowTextLength(hEdit);
wchar_t buffer[num+1];
GetWindowTextW( hEdit, buffer, num+1);
FILE* file = _wfopen( L"test.txt", L"w,ccs=UTF-8" );
fwprintf( file, L"%s", buffer );
```

Above code doesn't write `ï` `»` `¿` `CR` `LF` in the file, but:

> `ï` `»` `¿` `CR` `CR` `LF` (EF BB BF 0D 0D 0A)

No way here to use the `"b"` binary mode to avoid the `CR` addition.

```
FILE* file = _wfopen( L"test.txt", L"wb,ccs=UTF-8" );
```

Writes in the file the expected `\r\n` but encoded UTF-16, without any BOM:

> `CR` `NUL` `LF` `NUL` (0D 00 0A 00)

How avoid this `CR` proliferation for a UTF-8 file?
Am I forced to encode it UTF-16?

Thanks for any suggestion.

Comment: I really don't think wide character versions of I/O functions know anything about UTF-8. That's not a "wide" encoding, it's a variable-width one.

Comment: To use `"b"` and `"\r"` or not depends on an unstated coding goal: Do you want to print files exactly the same, even if code is compiled on various platforms (Use `"b"` and the line ending of choice `"\r\n"` or `"\n"`)?  Or do you want the line ending to be what the compiler natively produces.  (do not use  `"b"` and `"\r"`).  What do you want _across_ platforms?  This is really a compiler section, not an OS selection.

Comment: @unwind: `_wfopen` and `fwprintf` perfectly manage UTF-8, thanks to flag `"ccs=UTF-8"` they add the `ï»¿` BOM and make all characters conversion on a wide character input. The only fault is to [translate each linefeed into a carriage return / linefeed combination during output](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa273067.aspx).

Comment: @chux: I'm writing a Windows program.

If I use `"b"` the output won't be UTF-8.

I can't choose the line ending, it's `\r\n` because stream comes from an [Edit control](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb775456.aspx).

Comment: "That writes in the file `ï»¿CRCRLF`" is without context.  What tool was used to determined the contents were `ï»¿CRCRLF`?  What is the _binary_  content of `"test.txt"`?  And how is that wrong?  What was the expectation?   Byte-order-marks are often use at the beginning of files.  Is a mis-interpreted [`ï»¿` a BOM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark)?

Comment: Under Windows, for text files, the streams I/O functions convert CRLF on input to just LF (NL, `'\n'`), and on output convert just LF to CRLF ('\r\n').  That means you don't have to do the mapping in your code.  So, use `fprintf( file, "%s", "\n" );` and your hex dump of the file will find that the CR is also present.  Alternatively, as already suggested, use binary mode; then you are responsible for everything and if you want CRLF line endings, you have to write them.

Comment: @Salvador Oh, thanks. I had no idea.

Comment: @chux: The tool is a function I wrote that opens a file and unveils hidden chars like `\r` `\n`.  I edited my question thanks to your questions.

Comment: Wide character are **not** unicode, not UTF-8, not UTF-16. This is a obsolete feature.

Comment: 1)   For debugging suggest `fopen( "test_debug.txt", "wb" );` followed perhaps with a `fwrite(... BOM, 3,...);`  2) BTW, _Why_ do you not want `EF BB BF 0D 0D 0A`?  By having that "extra" `'\r'` there, the file can be read by code and recreate the same `buffer`.  If you process out the `'\r'`, when code reads the file it can not distinguish if the original `buffer` was `"abc\r\n"` or `"abc\n"`.

Comment: The edit control uses `\r\n` to delimit lines, and there's not much you can do about it except manually go through and remove the `\r`s (being sure to add them back when filling the edit control again later). I'm pretty sure passing a bare `\n` to `fprintf()` will cause it to be transparently converted to `\r\n`, in which case you'll probably also have to convert to UTF-8 and back yourself. You can use `WideCharToMultiByte()` to do this, but if you write your own UTF-16 processing loop, you'll be able to combine both the `\r\n` elimination and the encoding conversion into a single loop.

Comment: The simple truth is that the standard text line ending on Windows is `\r\n`, and has been since CP/M, and the C standard library is written to reflect this, and programs that handle anything else have the logic to do so built in.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As suggested, a possible solution is remove all `CR`s before writing `buffer` into file.
Then `fwprintf` cares to put a `CR` before each `LF` restoring the pairs `\r\n`.

```
HWND hEdit = CreateWindowW( L"Edit", ... );
int num = GetWindowTextLength(hEdit);
wchar_t buffer[num+1];
GetWindowTextW( hEdit, buffer, num+1 );

for( int i=0, id=0; id<=num; i++, id++ ) {
    while( buffer[id]=='\r' )
        id++;
    buffer[i] = buffer[id]; 
}

FILE* file = fopen( "test.txt", "w,ccs=UTF-8" );    
fwprintf( file, L"%s", buffer );
fclose(file);
```